# get percentage fro array of objects using angular 6

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular6, javascript-objects, percentage

i want to get percentage of particular object, like:
I have an options array:-

```
options: Array(2)
0: {id: 1, choice: "Yes", answer_count: 1}
1: {id: 2, choice: "No", answer_count: 0}
```

or mcq array:-

```
options: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, choice: "Yes, of course", answer_count: 0}
1: {id: 2, choice: "There is not an immediate need in the product, I a…d it to get a basic understanding of the subject.", answer_count: 1}
2: {id: 3, choice: "This will help me to pursue my learning goal.", answer_count: 0}
3: {id: 4, choice: "No,  I am not sure if it was helpful enough", answer_count: 0}
```

I need to get the percentage of `choice key` from total number of `answer_count key`
like: percentage of `choice: "Yes, ofcourse"` from `answer count of choice: "Yes, ofcourse" to the total of all answer count in options`

Can someone help me in finding a solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of the answer_count property with:

```
choices.map(function(item) {
    return item['answer_count']
})
```

Then you can reduce that array to get the amount of answers like this:

```
choices.map(function(item) {return item['answer_count']}).reduce(function (a, b) { 
    return (a + b)
});
```

Finally, just get the percentage by dividing the answer_count by the amount and multiply the result by 100:

```
(item['answer_count'] / totalAnswers) * 100
```

Using the data you provided:

```js
let choices = [
  {id: 1, choice: "Yes, of course", answer_count: 0},
  {id: 2, choice: "There is not an immediate need in the product, I a…d it to get a basic understanding of the subject.", answer_count: 1},
  {id: 3, choice: "This will help me to pursue my learning goal.", answer_count: 0},
  {id: 4, choice: "No,  I am not sure if it was helpful enough", answer_count: 0}
];

let totalAnswers = choices.map(function(item) {return item['answer_count']}).reduce(function (a, b) { 
  return (a + b)
});

let percentages = choices.map(function (item) {
  return {
    'id': item['id'],
    'choice': item['choice'], 
    'percentage': (item['answer_count'] / totalAnswers) * 100
  }
})

console.log(percentages);
```